# Is the "Ser Lyonel" Arya runs an errand for also the son of Emmon Frey?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In A Clash of Kings, the Appendix lists under House Frey:

> Emmon's son, SER LYONEL, m. Melesa Crakehall

And earlier in page 486, Arya's chapter, she runs an errand for a Ser Lyonel:

> "Weasel," Weese said that afternoon. "Get to the armory and tell Lucan that **Ser Lyonel** notched his sword in practice and needs a new one."

Arya doesn't know the man, so I'm not sure that the Ser Lyonel in Harrenhal is the same as the Ser Lyonel Frey mentioned in the Appendix, Lord Walder's grandson. Is it possible, i.e. were there Freys in Harrenhal at this point in the series?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While it is never confirmed, it is suspected that these are the same person: [Ser Lyonel Frey](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lyonel_Frey), second son of Emmon Frey and Genna Lannister. This actually makes him quite high up on the Frey line of succession, Walder Frey's second son's second son, but still quite unlikely to inherit any titles.

It may be that he decided to go into service with his mothers side of the family, they being the richest family in Westeros, or he may be a plant for the Frey's schemes.

Either way, the Frey's get everywhere. If this is Lyonel, he isn't the only Frey on the Lannister side, his younger brother [Tion Frey](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tion_Frey) was captured along side Ser Jaime Lannister in *A Game of Thrones, Chapter 63.*

Comment: Nice point about other Frey's in Lannister service.

Comment: Agreed. Nice well-thought out answer. I'm compiling a database of characters and am not entirely sure what to do about Lyonel, whether to assume he is a Frey or include him as a separate entry. The latter is probably the safer choice given there's no confirmation of which Lyonel he is and at least six Lyonels to choose from, according to [AWOIAF](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/List_of_characters#L)

Comment: Yea probably for the best, awoiaf wiki has two listings for this because of the ambiguity of these two references. The one I linked above and http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lyonel

Comment: Looks like all Lyonel Frey's brothers sided with their mother and the Lannisters: [Cleos](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Cleos_Frey) fought with and was captured with Jaime, just like [Tion](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tion_Frey), and the youngest, ["Red Walder"](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Walder_Frey_(son_of_Emmon)), is a page at Casterly rock. So it's make sense for Lyonel Frey to be with the  Lannister army. If it's not the same Lyonel, he's the only one of those siblings we know nothing about.